# Command line arguments with spaces to a C program through shell-wrapper script

Tags: c, command-line-arguments

what does it take to make my program accept command-line arguments with spaces?

**Yet-another EDIT**: I have just recognized that the program is started from a shell-script that sets up the environment for the execution of the program. As there are some external libraries, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is set to the current working directory:

```
#!/bin/sh

ARCH=`uname -m`
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=".:lib/magic/linux-${ARCH}"

./data_sniffer.bin $*

exit $?
```

The issue is definitely related to `$*`. Is there any solution to correctly forward the command-line parameters?

Here is a code-snippet from `main()`:

```
if (stat(argv[1], &lStat) != 0)
{   
    fprintf(stderr, "Cannot stat(2) given file: %s. \n", argv[1]);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

I am starting my program with the following parameters:

```
./data_sniffer /mnt/pod/movies/some\ test\ movie\ file.avi
```

The resulting error message looks like this:
    Cannot stat(2) given file: /mnt/pod/movies/some.

Anyone an idea what's wrong here? I think that I am not the first one with this problem (though, I could not find a related question here).

Comment: Hi Mat, I am sorry, but this was a mistake. Please think that it is argv[1] (already edited in the question).

Comment: My answer has been updated with relevant information to solve your problem, in the future **do not** post a question and then decide to change it - it's very annoying to us who decide to answer the first one and then realize that it was completely pointless.

Comment: I am sorry for doing this. Maybe I should start a new question instead of changing the existing one the next time. Thank you for your useful answer. It solved my problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace the use of `./data_sniffer.bin $*` with `./data_sniffer.bin "$@"` in your wrapper script and the arguments should be forwarded in a correct manner.

More regarding the difference between `$*`, `$@` and `"$@"` can be found [here](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/scrpt/scrpt2.2.2.html).

---

> <sup>the author of this question changed it completely and came forward with more information regarding the matter, I will let everything already written stand but please remember that this was written before his/her last edit..</sup>

---

#### Regarding `argv`..

It doesn't require much from you as a developer, I'm tempted (and it's much more truthful) to say that it requires **nothing** of you.

Arguments passed to the application is handled by the shell executing the binary, doing this below should definitely work the way you want it to (even though I find it odd that you are claiming that the current shell doesn't handle `'\ '` correctely):

```
./data_sniffer '/mnt/pod/movies/some test movie file.avi'
./data_sniffer /mnt/pod/movies/some\ test\ movie\ file.avi

# there should be no difference between the two
```

---

#### My recommendation(s)

- Have you tried doing `printf ("argv[1]: %s\n", argv[1]);` in the beginning of main to validate the contents of it?
- Are you sure that you are invoking the correct binary with the correct *command-line* arguments?

Sadly the only reasonable thing to write is that you are doing something wrong. We are however unable to answer what without further information regarding the issue.

<sup>I find it very hard to believe that there is a bug in your *shell*, even though that is of course possible - I doubt it.</sup>

---

Parsing the *command-line* into `argv` isn't something that you as a developer should worry about, there are no enforced functionality that you have to implement for the binary itself to handle spaces in it's argument(s).

Comment: It does not work for me, both with quotes and backslash-escaping. Actually, that is what I was thinking too: the command-line arguments are put into `argv` as given: un-escaped (backslashes removed; spaces preserved).

Answer (score 4):

In my CentOS 5.3, I made a test.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
        printf("argc=%d\n", argc);
        int i = 0;
        for(i = 0; i<argc; i++)
        {   
                printf("argv[%d]=%s\n", i, argv[i]);
        }   
        return 0;
}
```

And then run it with different parameters:

```
[root@dw examples]# ./a.out a b c
argc=4
argv[0]=./a.out
argv[1]=a
argv[2]=b
argv[3]=c
[root@dw examples]# ./a.out 'a b c'
argc=2
argv[0]=./a.out
argv[1]=a b c
[root@dw examples]# ./a.out a\ b\ c
argc=2
argv[0]=./a.out
argv[1]=a b c
[root@dw examples]# ./a.out "a b c"
argc=2
argv[0]=./a.out
argv[1]=a b c
```

So looks like (1) 'a b c' ; (2) a\ b\ c; (3) "a b c" all are working.

Comment: Thank you so much for performing a test setting! Please see my new edit. The issue is related to the wrapper script (did not think of it as a source of error) that invokes my program.